# Horrible graphics on my Dell Inspiron 17 with Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, display

I just got a new laptop: Dell Inspiron 17 (3737) BTX Base.  The graphic card is Intel® HD Graphics 4400

I installed Ubuntu 13.10.

The graphics are just horrible. It looks like an old 4 bits color display or something.

I ran the system testing tool and I got the following results:

`graphics/driver_version    FAILED  ERROR: No video driver loaded! Possibly in failsafe mode!`

It looks like the video driver is not installed properly. How can I fix this?

Here is some additional info:

```
lspci -nn | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 09)
```

I also tried the [Intel Graphics Installer](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.3-linux), but nothing changed. Still stuck with the same problem.

Thanks,

Comment: Try reinstalling.

Answer (score 2):

Well, my identical machine does the same (inspiron 17 3737 - processor i3-4010U with hd4400). The RGB signal is all messed up.

Weirdly enough , when I connect a display on the HDMI port, that one works fine.

If you only need 1 display, and not much graphics : boot with `NOMODESET` (procedure to do this can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu/38834#38834) ).

Otherwise : Ubuntu 12.04, 13.04, 13.10, daily 14 do not solve the problem, with or without update, with or without the `1.0.3` or `1.0.4` Intel drivers from Intel 01.org

Answer (score 0):

It's an intel chipset so there are no proprietary drivers to install, just the mesa open source drivers from intel.

Type this in a terminal (ctrl+alt+t) :

sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel

and that should install the driver.

You could also download the intel driver installer from here :

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.4-linux