# Display screen resolution not correct in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: display, resolution

https://askubuntu.com/questions/532024/display-setting-are-incorrect-and-cant-be-changed-in-system-setting-for-ubuntu

I have a problem with screen display that the header is not shown in full font (just like to "Ubuntu Desktop" in the link shown above) after I changed the "resolution" and "scale for menu and title bar" in the Display setting.  What should I do?
The graphic card is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 0b) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:060a]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 59
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing drives for intel graphics driver.They are available on its site.(But usually Intel drivers are installed by default in Ubuntu.I use Intel Graphics and I had no problem.)
Here's a link to a similar problem
[Intel Graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428703/horrible-graphics-on-my-dell-inspiron-17-with-ubuntu-13-10)